# Portal for ArcGIS 10.3.1 bad visualization after installation

Tags: arcgis-10.3, arcgis-portal

It's been a week now since we upgraded our version from 10.3 to 10.3.1 and right after the upgrade we had many visual problems when browsing the portal on IE, such as bad width of the top menu bar when the "My organization" button shows up in 2 lines, the search bar shows up always on the left side beneath the menu bar instead of being at the right side, maps got scrambled like a puzzle in a very weird way and more... see attached screenshots

Today I removed the Portal + Web Adaptor + Data Store + deleted their libraries! which means pretty much a complete clean re-installation from scratch with no previous settings or content.

Installed it again, and the same problems shows up! - no scrambled maps, but all other visual problems I've mentioned (see attach screenshots).

Removed everything again! installed IE version 11 and then tried to reinstall the portal again, and still nothing changed - you can see it's wrong immediately at the first portal window when he asks to create a new user - screenshot file named clean_installation!

Do anyone knows or ever experienced this issue?? I got some support from ESRI and others but still no one managed to reproduce or understand where this issues comes from.

I should also add that it happens ONLY on IE (any version!) and not other browsers - my organization is not going to leave IE anytime soon so it's not a choice.

Pretty sure it's a server side installation issue since the behavior is the same from any machine browsing to the portal regardless the IE version and the ArcGIS Online version is shown great at that same IE that shows all problems.

When I browse to the online version with that same IE (that shows all those problems), everything is shown perfectly fine!

[image: first screen after a clean installation with a visual error on top menu bar]
[image: more screenshots from a few days ago before reinstalling everything]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer is likely running in Compatibility View which makes it emulate IE7 which is no longer supported. A cause could be that IE is set to use Compatibility View for all sites in the Intranet Zone and it is auto-detecting the URL as being an internal URL which by default places it in the intranet zone.

Comment: Very embarrassing to admit but it was actually the Compatibility View which is responsible for the problem.. after taking your suggestion it actually solved it after many months of attempts through the proxy :( thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Philip, I actually forgot about this thread. We found that the proxy server which our organization works with is the one to corrupt the view. Still not solved but we have the source of the problem.

Thanks anyway

Comment: Very embarrassing to admit but it was actually the Compatibility View which is responsible for the problem.. after taking your suggestion it actually solved it after many months of attempts through the proxy :( thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To be honest this kind of problem happens after EVERY upgrade. The most common cause is that there are still files being cached. I know you said that there was an uninstall of IE but who knows what windows holds onto.

Delete all your browser cache and do a hard refresh ( ctrl+f5 for IE ) and see if it doesn't look any better.